# Calculate speed of object placed in the middle of two other objects with different speeds and directions

Tags: java, android, physics

I have two Points in 2D

```
//Point1 has velocity 
vX = 100;
vY = 50;
posX = 300;
posY = 100;


//Point2  has velocity 
vX = -20;
vY = 80;
posX = -800;
posY = 1000;
```

Additional I have a point which is placed directly in the middle of these two points, how can i calculate speed of this middle point ?

Comment: Are the points connected? Do they have mass or a gravitational effect on each other? Are they colliding, or are you combining them in any way?

Comment: no, just two objects only with these parameters and virtual one between them

Comment: Then I don't think I understand - if the existing points don't affect the new one, then the new point isn't moving (or has whatever speed you give it). Can you explain more how these points are related, and what you mean by "virtual" point?

Comment: @Tim imagine you had a pair of handcuffs that could expand at will, and when it expanded or contracted it always did so equally on both sides. If you put a red dot in the center of the connecting chain, then set the cuffs in motion, you could track the red dot as it moved.

Comment: @Tim I need this for my 2D game (view from top), two planes are moving with different speed in different directions. I need to place camera in the middle of them and set velocity to this camera so it will follow the point between them. Velocity of camera will be velocity of this point in the middle.

Comment: Pawel: that makes much more sense, and I agree with corsiKa's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By determining what it's vX and vY are.

Its x and y are

```
x = (-800 - 20 * t + 300 + 100 * t) / 2
y = (1000 + 80 * t + 100 + 50 * t) / 2
```

Simplify

```
x = -250 + 40 * t
y = 550 + 65 * t
```

so it's vX is 40 and its vy is 65. My friend Pythagoras tells me the speed here is `sqrt((40 * 40) + (65 * 65))` or roughly **76 units per tick**.